# Controller of collection form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony

I'm beginner on symfony and I have to use the collection form to make a site to reserve tickets for a show.

The interface is simple, The user select the number of tickets he wants, then it display as much form prototype (name and surname input) as tickets required.
This part works well for me.

I have 2 table "reservations" and "ticket" in mysql and I would like to get this render after submiting the form:

**Table reservation :**

Reservation id = 1

**Table ticket:**

Ticket id="1" name="thomas", surname="good", reservation_id="1"

Ticket id="2" name="laura", surname="senior", reservation_id="1"

---

But when I submit my form, I get +1 reservation in my table but no data in my ticket table.

```html
class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function formAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $reservation = new Reservations();

        $form = $this->createForm(new ReservationsType(), $reservation, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('louvre_pages_homepage'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $em->persist($reservation);

        $em->flush();


        return $this->render('LouvrePagesBundle:Pages:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
}
```

```html
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tickets', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'    => TicketType::class,
                'allow_add'     => true,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'by_reference'  => false,
                'prototype' => true,
                )
            )
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'attr'      => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success'
                )
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'reservations';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Louvre\PagesBundle\Entity\Reservations',
        ));
    }
```

Is my controller right ?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems in the `formAction`:

1. there is no call to `$em->flush();` anywhere
2. you are always calling `$em->persist($reservation);` regardless of the form validation state

Try doing it this way:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($reservation);
    $em->flush();

    // now redirect, add flash message, etc.
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: Also possibly cascade persist will need to be set on reservation -> ticket: or tickets should be persisted individually.

Comment: ShiraNai I tried your code, but I see the both conditions are not respected and when I remove the IF condition, it add reservation but no ticket data as I told before

Comment: @ThomasGood Make sure the `action` is correct. Does `louvre_pages_homepage` route to `formAction` of that controller?

Comment: Yes it does :

louvre_pages_homepage:
    path:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: LouvrePagesBundle:Advert:form }

Comment: @ThomasGood You wrote _the both conditions are not respected_ - so both `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()` yield `false`? Does the profiler and/or form show any errors?

Comment: @ShiraiNai Yes the both doesn't works 

See the screenshot below  after submit:

http://www.noelshack.com/2016-21-1464036428-ded.jpg

Comment: In my request parameters it looks like it works ( i think ) but it don't:

http://www.noelshack.com/2016-21-1464036896-fef.jpg

Comment: @ThomasGood Odd. What does the "Forms" page of the profiler show?

Comment: @ShiraNai7

http://www.noelshack.com/2016-21-1464045110-ff.png

http://www.noelshack.com/2016-21-1464044877-yhy.png

(Billets mean tickets)

Comment: @ThomasGood How are you rendering the form? If it's custom, try replacing it with `{{ form(form) }}`. If that doesn't help, you might have to dig into `handleRequest()` and debug it to figure out why the request data isn't being accepted.

Comment: {{ form_start(form) }}


    <ul class="tickets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tickets.vars.prototype)|e }}">


    </ul>

    {{ form_end(form) }}

Comment: @ThomasGood Try doing this: 1) render the form by simply using `{{ form(form) }}` (no prototypes) 2) disable `'prototype'` on the tickets collection 3) add a few empty tickets to Reservations in the controller (for testing) 4) see if the form works in this simplified form - if yes, work backwards to find out what's causing it to break - if it still doesn't work, try debugging the `handleRequest()` method.. can't really help you anymore without running the app myself.

Comment: It's ok I fixed the problem it was the settings in my Entity, I forget to add

"cascade={"persist","remove"}" to my reservation entity.